# Reveals a Renaming!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> > ***A List of the Ten Most Valuable Brands in the World This Financial Year:***
>
> 1. Amazon;
> 2. Apple;
> 3. Google;
> 4. The Samsung Group;
> 5. Facebook;
> 6. AT&T (American Telephone & Telegraph);
> 7. Microsoft;
> 8. Verizon;
> 9. Walmart; &
> 10. The Industrial and Commercial Bank of China.

A brief description of each of them:

> 1. Online retail trailblazer;
> 2. Computers, phones, TV;
> 3. Internet web, a mega 'billboard';
> 4. Phones, gadgets;
> 5. Think talkathon, fandom, crazy election havoc (hahaha!);
> 6. Mass media;
> 7. Software;
> 8. Communications;
> 9. Full of popular retail; &
> 10. Mortgage, finance.

## What one word describes how I have named each brand?

There might be many, though I am looking for an $8$-letter word that is actually one of the tags on this site! <s>I will include that tag after I have accepted an answer (or else it would spoil the puzzle).</s>

This is not my puzzle, and will [provide attribution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) after I have accepted an answer. For users who've seen (or might have seen) this puzzle before...

> ...lucky you.

The title is also a clue.

Comment: I'd suggest *not* including the "answer tag" after it's found. The [tag:enigmatic] tag is fine by itself and adding the tag would be a spoiler, even when the correct answer is given, right?

Comment: @Chowzen yeah, true. Okey, then, if you say so. I have edited the question accordingly :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the word is

> Anagrams

Because

> if you take all of letters of the first list, including "A List of the Ten Most Valuable Brands in the World This Financial Year", you can anagram it into the second list

Possible title clue

> Title "Reveals a Renaming!" is an anagram of "Anagrams Never Lie".

Comment: Hmmm... which title? :P

Comment: @user477343 edited to answer your additional question

Comment: Well, you are correct! Nicely done! And... (ROT13) Lbh pna nyfb nantenz gur gvgyr, npghnyyl, naq vg jvyy, jryy, erirny n eranzvat. But anyway, how did you figure this out? Have you seen this puzzle before? :P

Comment: Reveals a Renaming : Name Range Revisal.

Comment: @Chowzen that was not the intended one, but that works :D

Comment: Nah, it's fine. I am glad to accept this answer after three/four days if nobody else has answered :)

Comment: @user477343  Added possible title help

Comment: Yes, that is the correct one :D

Comment: (Pedantry alert: This post has "and mega billboard", but it should be "a", not "and".)

Comment: @MOehm no, it refers to how Google is an "internet web" *and* a "mega billboard", without the "an" and "a" :)

Comment: Whoops. Forgot to tick this answer. Congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: @user477343: I don't understand your answer. I tried to point out (without spoilers) that the two lists are not anagrams of each other with "and", because you get an extra n and an extra d. [The original](https://www.anagramtimes.com/2018/09/the-10-most-valuable-brands-in-2018.html) has it right.

Comment: @MOehm I am pretty sure that's what the anagram includes. It includes the word "and". I will double check. **Edit:** Yes, you are correct. I will fix that. Thank you for pointing that out! :)